# Writing a value to an Excel cell

Tags: excel, vb.net, excel-interop

I'm aiming to create a simple ribbon with a button that set cell (A1) value to "Hello World!" in the active work sheet.

I have this code but it returns an error and I have no idea what I'm doing wrong.

Screenshot of error:

[image]

Code:

```
Imports Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel

Public Class Ribbon1

    Private Sub Ribbon1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As RibbonUIEventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As RibbonControlEventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim xlApp As New Excel.Application
        Dim xlBook As Excel.Workbook
        Dim xlSheet As Excel.Worksheet

        xlBook = xlApp.ActiveWorkbook
        xlSheet = xlBook.ActiveSheet

        With xlSheet
            .Range("A1").Value = "Hello World!"
        End With
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to *add* a new `Workbook` before you can do anything with it:

```
xlApp.Workbooks.Add()
```

I would also consider declaring a `Range` to use:

```
Dim xlRange As Excel.Range = xlSheet.Range("A1")
xlRange.Value = "Hello World!"
```

Your code would look something similar to this:

```
Dim xlApp As New Excel.Application
Dim xlBook As Excel.Workbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add()
Dim xlSheet As Excel.Worksheet = CType(xlBook.ActiveSheet, Excel.Worksheet)

Dim xlRange As Excel.Range = xlSheet.Range("A1")
xlRange.Value = "Hello World!"
```

Also please turn [Option Strict On](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcd4xwzs.aspx):

> Restricts implicit data type conversions to only widening conversions, disallows late binding, and disallows implicit typing that results in an Object type.